# Can you share heap memory between two processes? (Rust and Node)

Tags: node.js, rust, memory-management

I am designing a program that is written in Rust but allows for configuration to be supplied by the end user in the form of JavaScript code.

At the moment, I am thinking of having the Rust application initialize, spawn a Node instance in a sub-shell controlled by the Rust process which wraps the Node process's stdin/stdout to communicate with it - likely sending/receiving JSON (or similar).

This works but I would need to send large amounts of data between the two processes so the overhead of serialization will become problematic.

I am wondering if it's possible to share heap memory between the independent processes. I would like the Rust application to create a heap and then both the Rust and Node process to access the same heap.

I would imagine that Node does not have a built-in API to access this heap, so I would assume I'd need to create a "native module" in Rust that Node would use to interact with the shared heap.

I understand that memory stored there would have to be stored such that it would be consumable by both processes, manually (unsafely) being cast to the correct data type to be interacted with - that's fine.

In this scenario, is there a way to use atomics (to avoid race conditions)?

This needs to work on Windows, MacOS and Linux - do they all have different APIs for creating this "shared heap"?.

Comment: All those OSes should support [shared memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_memory) (note Windows implements it via memory-mapped files, not "true" shared memory).

Comment: How much is "large amounts of data" that you want to share?  What is the format of this data?  Is it binary?  How do you expect to access and process that data in nodejs?  As a binary buffer?

Comment: It would be much simpler IMO to embed a JavaScript runtime (via the [js-sandbox](https://crates.io/crates/js-sandbox) crate perhaps) into your Rust application instead of spawning a child process and dealing with shared memory. (especially if the JavaScript is only there for "configuration" but then I wonder why it needs to access heaps of data...)

Comment: I considered embedding a JS runtime however consumers would need access to node-sims (like importing dependencies from `node_modules` and the Node standard library). I have an enormous graph structure that is a few gigabytes in size, the user supplied JS configuration has callbacks on events with access to the graph - allowing them to act as a middleware to access/modify the graph. Maybe the stdio approach would work if the config callbacks were supplied getters/setters to interact with the graph, only transferring from Rust to Node if a plugin interacts - hoping for a more elegant solution

Comment: So, if this GBs of data is in your Rust program, then it cannot be directly accessed via Javascript as normal Javascript data structures.  Javascript has its own way of storing and referencing data which is not what Rust uses.  So, it's completely unclear how you ever intended for Javascript to access this data directly from Rust, even if it it was somehow in shared memory.  Javascript could access a binary data structure in shared memory (by manually piecing pieces of data together and knowing about  byte ordering and data sizes), but that's not easy for end-user Javascript to do properly.

Comment: It sounds to me like you need to back up several steps and describe the full problem here before people can offer you architectural choices because the path you're going down of access the same physical GBs of memory in two separate processes (Rust and Nodejs) where the nodejs is end-user written Javascript is not likely a feasible path.

Comment: FYI, the data could be put into an in-memory database such as Redis and both programs could access it from there with well-defined APIs from both languages and concurrency management tools in the database.